# Add 2 new column header and contents in csv file using php

Tags: php, csv

I've an existing csv  file with following values

```
column1 column2
Fr-fc   Fr-sc
Sr-fc   Sr-sc
```

I want to add 2 new columns in it and achieve the following format

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
Fr-fc   Fr-sc     1        2
Sr-fc   Sr-sc     1        2
```

If I use following code it inserts same column header value in column data for the newly created columns

```
$a = file('amit.csv');// get array of lines
$new = '';
foreach($a as $line){
    $line = trim($line);// remove end of line
    $line .=";column3";// append new column
    $line .=";column4";// append new column
    $new .= $line.PHP_EOL;//append end of line
}
file_put_contents('amit2.csv', $new);// overwrite the same file with new data
```

How I can achieve the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you can use php's inbuilt csv functions [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) respectively to ease your work. First read in each row with `fgetcsv` and store the data in a multidimensional array:

```
$delimiter = "\t"; //your column separator
$csv_data = array();
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen('test.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
        $csv_data[] = $data;
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Next edit the rows to add the extra columns using [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$extra_columns = array('column3' => 1, 'column4' => 2);
foreach ($csv_data as $i => $data) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        $csv_data[$i] = array_merge($data, array_keys($extra_columns));
    } else {
        $csv_data[$i] = $data = array_merge($data, $extra_columns);
    }
}
```

Finally use `fputcsv` to enter each row into the csv.

```
if (($handle = fopen('test.csv', 'w')) !== FALSE) {
    foreach ($csv_data as $data) {
        fputcsv($handle, $data, $delimiter);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

You can combine these steps to make your code more efficient by reducing the number of loops.

Comment: How to adapt your code to concatenate the values of two columns of the csv file?

Comment: This was Really helpful, Thank you bro.

Answer (score 6):

This approach is less code

```
<?php
$inFile = fopen('test.csv','r');
$outFile = fopen('output.csv','w');

$line = fgetcsv($inFile);
while ($line !== false) {
        $line[] = 'third column';
        $line[] = 'fourth column';
        fputcsv($outFile, $line);
        $line = fgetcsv($inFile);
}
fclose($inFile);
fclose($outFile);
```