# How to add a new column in an existing csv with hundreds of records and populate it from an array?

Tags: php, csv

**I am trying to populate a csv file like this.**

existing.csv

```
header1 header2    header3  
record  record2    record3  
itemXYZ numberXYZ  item40   
data1   dataABC    anydata  
etcA    etc3       etcX5a
...
```

total rows = 522

records & items can be any string or number.

**Data to insert in "newHeader"**

```
array (size=522)
  0 => string 'Global' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Press' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Insurance' (length=9)
  3 => string 'Presse' (length=6)
  4 => string 'Insurance' (length=10)
  5 => string 'Global' (length=6)
  6 => string 'Assurances' (length=10)
  7 => string 'Global' (length=6)
  8 => string 'Global' (length=6)
  9 => string 'Global' (length=6)
 10 => ...
```

**The result should be like this :**

```
header1 header2    header3  newHeader
record  record2    record3  Global 
itemXYZ numberXYZ  item40   Press
data1   dataABC    anydata  Insurance,
etcA    etc3       etcX5a   Presse
...
```

I use a slightly modified code from another post here  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36143377/11256861).

```
foreach ($cat as $value) {
        writeToCsv($value);
   }

function writeToCsv($value) {

$delimiter = ','; //your column separator
$csv_data = array();
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen('input/existing_populated.csv', 'r')) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== false) {
        $csv_data[] = $data;
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$extra_columns = array('columnName' => $value);
foreach ($csv_data as $i => $data) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        $csv_data[$i] = array_merge($data, array_keys($extra_columns));
    } else {
        $csv_data[$i] = array_merge($data, $extra_columns);
    }
}

if (($handle = fopen('output/result.csv', 'w')) !== false) {
    foreach ($csv_data as $data) {
        fputcsv($handle, $data, $delimiter);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
}
```

At the end, this method fills all rows with the latest category read from the foreach loop. Which is obvious. But I can't figure out how to "distribute" each category from new column to existing records.

Thank you for your help.

**Solution based on @bestprogrammerintheworld post**

I made a small modification. My categories array already includes the header. I don't know whether this is the best practice but it clearly works. Thanks to @bestprogrammerintheworld

```
$delimiter = ',';
$csv_data = array();
if (($handle = fopen('input/existing_populated.csv', 'r')) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== false) {
        $csv_data[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$row = 0;
foreach ($cat as $index => $item) {
    if ($row === 0) {
        $csv_data[$index + $row][] = $item;
    } else {
        $csv_data[$index + 1][] = $item;
    }
}

//Save new array to csv
if (($handle = fopen('output/result.csv', 'w')) !== false) {
    foreach ($csv_data as $data) {
        fputcsv($handle, $data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: What is going on with `$csv_data[$i] = $data = array_merge()` in the else branch, what is the purpose of overwriting $data there?

Comment: Why is this three separate loops to begin with, why not just _one_? Read line from original CSV, add the new data to the line data, write modified line data into result file.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe. I'll see what I can do with your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$newHeader = array(
    'Global',
    'Press',
    'Insurance',
    'Presse',
    'Insurance',
    'Global',
    'Assurances',
    'Global'
);


//Load csv file
$delimiter = ';';
$csv_data = array();
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen('input/existing_populated.csv', 'r')) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== false) {
        $csv_data[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

/*
    Now the output of $csv_data looks something like:
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => header1
        [1] => header2
        [2] => header3
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => record
        [1] => record2
        [2] => record3
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => itemXYZ
        [1] => numberXYZ
        [2] => item40
    )

    [3] => Array
        (
        [0] => data1
        [1] => dataABC
        [2] => anydata

*/

//Add header to array
$csv_data[0][] = 'newHeader'; (is [0][3] below)

/*
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => header1
        [1] => header2
        [2] => header3
        [3] => newHeader
    )
*/

//Add data to array ($index is only viable here if $newHeader 
//is indexed by 0,1,2 etc)
/* $newHeader = array(
    'Global',
    'Press'...

    makes $newHeader[0] (Global), $newHeader{1] Press etc...
 */
foreach($newHeader as $index=>$item) {
    $csv_data[$index + 1][] = $item;
}

//Save new array to csv
if (($handle = fopen('output/result.csv', 'w')) !== false) {
    foreach ($csv_data as $data) {
        fputcsv($handle, $data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @bestprogrammerintheworld. You deserve your name. I modified my post to include your solution.

Comment: @David . Thanks (even if the alias is very ironic)